# Smaato test mode in android

Tags: android, smaato

I have connected `Smaato` API to my Android app. This app not yet in Play Store. I want to test it before. But I don't see any banners at all. I have provided right Publisher ID and Adspace ID but nothing.

How can I run `Smaato` test mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your Publisher ID = 0 and Adspace ID = 0